# Difference between align-items vs align content & justify-items vs justify-content

Tags: flexbox, grid

Can someone please explain me the Difference between align-items vs align content & justify-items vs justify-content. I am really getting hard time in understanding the core meaning, purpose and usage of these css properties.

Which property goes with flexbox and which one for grid?